# Change an inner div while hovering the container

Tags: html, css

I've managed to make it work on Chrome... But in doesn't work on IE and Firefox...
I've no idea why.... Can someone help me?

```
<div id="rsscontainer" class="rss">
<div id="rssbutton" class="rss">
<div id="rssinner" class="rss">
<img src="imageurlhere">
```

```
  

    #rsscontainer {
    top: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    width:  20px;
    height: 20px;

    }

    #rssbutton {

     vertical-align: middle;
     width:  81px;
     height: 81px;
     position: absolute;
     left: -1px;
     top: -30px;
     padding: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
     border-right: 1px solid #e0e1e1; 
     border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e1e1;
     border-left: 1px solid #e0e1e1;
     background-color: #f5f7f7;
     -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px #f9fafa;
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px #f9fafa;
     box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px #f9fafa;
     z-index: 20;
     color: #f5f7f7;
     font-weight: bold;
     -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
     -moz-transition: all 200ms linear;
     -o-transition: all 200ms linear;
     -ms-transition: all 200ms linear;
     transition: all 200ms linear;
    }

    #rssbutton:hover {
      background-color: #f86c00;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px #f77918;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px #f77918;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px #f77918;
    border-right: 1px solid #d45d01; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d45d01;
    border-left: 1px solid #d45d01;

     -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 200ms linear;
    -ms-transition: all 200ms linear;
    transition: all 200ms linear;
    }

     #rssinner {
     position: relative;
     top: 14px;

          -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 200ms linear;
    -ms-transition: all 200ms linear;
    transition: all 200ms linear;

    }

    #rssbutton:hover > #rssinner {
    filter: brightness(0.5); invert(1);
    -webkit-filter: brightness(0.5) invert(1);
    -moz-filter: brightness(0.5) invert(1);
    -o-filter: brightness(0.5) invert(1);
    -ms-filter: brightness(0.5) invert(1);



        -webkit-transition: all 70ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 70ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 70ms linear;
    -ms-transition: all 70ms linear;
    transition: all 70ms linear;

    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/damix55/V6jvd/

Comment: CSS3 Transitions are only supported by IE10 and above. And FF 16 and above. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Comment: Compability for CSS filters is not great https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#Browser_compatibility

Comment: i don't think that this is the problem... adding something else like top: 1px; doesn't work anyway

Comment: When I added a `border:1px solid white`   to the outer:hover > #rssinner bit, it worked in IE for me.     So, I think the     `#rssbutton:hover > #rssinner` section is working just fine for IE, you just need to give it something it can do with.

Comment: yes, you're right, in IE it works! But in Firefox no... and i don't really know why...

Comment: i fixed it just using a white image instead of applying filters